# Typescript: Difficulty writing declaration for Emscripten Embind Module.Interface.Extend

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a Typescript declaration file for a Emscripten embind module, and I'm trying to get proper constructor autocomplete for classes that have been extended using Module.Interface.extend. I have a generic parameter T that should extend either one of multiple prototype interfaces (through overloads), and this works, as long as T is identical to the interface it should extend. Whenever I add a property to the input (T), it fails. I thought that T extends U whould allow any interface as long as it supports all of U, but it apparently does not work like that.

This is the declaration:

```
interface ILoggerPrototypeBase {
    write(level: LogLevel, message: string);
    __destruct__?();
}
interface ILoggerPrototype extends ILoggerPrototypeBase {
    __construct__?();
}
interface ILoggerPrototype1<T1> extends ILoggerPrototypeBase {
    __construct__?(a1: T1);
}
interface ILoggerPrototype2<T1, T2> extends ILoggerPrototypeBase {
    __construct__?(a1: T1, a2: T2);
}
interface ILoggerPrototype3<T1, T2, T3> extends ILoggerPrototypeBase {
    __construct__?(a1: T1, a2: T2, a3: T3);
}
class Logger {
    write(logLevel: number, message: string);

    static extend<T extends ILoggerPrototype>(name: string, loggerProto: T): { new(): Logger & T };
    static extend<T extends ILoggerPrototype1<T1>, T1>(name: string, loggerProto: T): { new(a1: T1): Logger & T };
    static extend<T extends ILoggerPrototype2<T1, T2>, T1, T2>(name: string, loggerProto: T): { new(arg1: T1, arg2: T2): Logger & T };
    static extend<T extends ILoggerPrototype3<T1, T2, T3>, T1, T2, T3>(name: string, loggerProto: T): { new(arg1: T1, arg2: T2, arg3: T3): Logger & T };
}
```

I was hoping that I then could do

```
const TestLogger = Logger.extend({ 
    __construct__(someString: string) {},
    write(logLevel: LogLevel, message: string) {},
    enableLogging() {},
    disableLogging() {}
})
```

But then I get "Object literal may only specify known properties and 'enableLogging' does not exist in type 'ILoggerPrototype3<{},{},{}>'

If I remove enableLogging and disableLogging, it finds the correct overload, and it works. But I dont want to return a constructor for the base interface (ILoggerPrototype..) but T

**UPDATE**: Thanks to [Nitzan Tomer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/942852/nitzan-tomer) I've come to realize I need to actually define the interface and specify the template arguments explicitly. So my solution is to use `extend` in the following manner:

```
interface ITestLogger extends cxg.ILoggerPrototype1<string> {
    enableLogging();
    disableLogging();
}

const TestLogger = cxg.Logger.extend<ITestLogger, string>('TestLogger', { 
    __construct__(someString: string) {
    },
    enableLogging() {
    },
    disableLogging() {
    },
    write(level: cxg.LogLevel, message: string) {
    }
});

var logger = new TestLogger('hurray!');
```

Comment: Where are `enableLogging` and `disableLogging` defined? I see no trace of those other then when you actually try to extend.

Comment: Those are not defined elsewhere. I was hoping that when I used `T extends ILoggerPrototype` that typescript would implicitly make T its own interface that extends ILoggerPrototype, and any additional properties would be part of that implicit interface. I tried defining another interface ITestLogger that extends ILoggerPrototype1<string>, and when I cast the literal to it, it almost works as expected, the one caveat being that it believe arg1 is a object, not a string. I can use strings as input, but I would like the autocomplete to say that the input should be a string, and not a object

Comment: What is this `ILoggerPrototype`? Can you please add it to your question? And other relevant info/code.

Comment: If I call with extend with explicitly defining the generic arguments, eg `extend<ITestLogger, string>` I get a string as arg1, but I was hoping it would infer that automatically due to ITestLogger<string>. In any case, this is not such a big deal, and I'm content with taking this approach

Comment: `ILoggerPrototype` is in the question. It is `ILoggerPrototype1` i actually used though, as `ILoggerPrototype` is for classes with no explicit constructor or a constructor with no arguments. In any case, I think I found the proper solution, and will update my question with the solution I went for

Comment: You should be able to answer your question and then select it as the right one. As you are a new user you can do that only 8 hours after the question was asked, but if the solution works with you then answer when you can so that it may help others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion I need to explicitly define a interface for the prototype, and call `extend` with the generic type arguments explicitly defined to achieve what I want. That means I should use `extend` like this

```
interface ITestLogger extends ILoggerPrototype1<string> {
    enableLogging();
    disableLogging();
}

const TestLogger = Logger.extend<ITestLogger, string>('TestLogger', { 
    __construct__(someString: string) {
    },
    enableLogging() {
    },
    disableLogging() {
    },
    write(level: LogLevel, message: string) {
    }
});
```